# Is it legal for any business to post a 46.03 sign in Texas?

Tags: texas, firearms

Texas penal code [46.03](https://statutes.capitol.texas.gov/Docs/PE/htm/PE.46.htm) covers places in which it is unlawful to carry a firearm even by concealed carry license holders.  This law only covers a small set of specific establishments that meet the criteria such as a courthouse, business that makes 51% of their income on alcohol, a school, etc.

Any other type of business can post a 30.06 or 30.07 sign to restrict the carrying of a firearm on the premises, or any generic "no guns" sign they want but they do no apply to license holders.

My question:  Is it legal for a business that is clearly not covered by penal code 46.03 to post a 46.03 sign?  Today I saw a thrift store displaying one and I'm almost positive they have no grounds to claim 46.03 but are they legally allowed to post it and is it legally binding in any way?